# How to adjust websocket binary frame length(limit is 113KB max) in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, binary, frame

When send blob with Websocket in Chrome. Blob has split to small block(Binary frame) automatic. Max size of block is 113KB, too much small Binary frame makes upload speed slower. How to solve this problem?

In firefox, the Bolb send in only one binary frame.

WebSocket Server based on netty(Max frame size 4MB):

```
      .childHandler(
          new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
              ch.pipeline()
                  .addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
                  .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
                  .addLast(new WebSocketServerCompressionHandler())
                  .addLast(
                      new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(
                          "/", null, true, 4194304
                      )
                  )
                  .addLast(new WebSocketFileHandler());
            }
          }
      );
```

Client Javascript send File(Blob) with Websocket:

```
websocket.send(File) //File size 1.7MB
```

Test in Firefox, only one Websocket Binary Frame. Cost 329ms.

```
begin time: 09:50:34.835
Over  time: 09:50:35.164
```

Test in Chorme, 15 Websocket Binary Frame. About 112KB per frame. Cos 2214ms.

```
begin time: 09:47:55.488
Over  time: 09:47:56.702
```

In Chrome, too much frame cost to much time to communication.

[Chrome Websocket frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EjEb.png)

Answer (score 0):

chromium bug report:

websocket text frames over 131k get truncated on Chrome for Mac

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=517090

Adjust max size of frame in Websocket

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=870965

The reason is server do not support "Receive fragmented message". When i change the server from netty to Gorilla WebSocket, the problem solved. Just one frame posted by chrome.

But speed of chrome is slower than firefox too.